# Removing a first post in favor of more complete answers

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-answers

**Background**

I posted an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19023490/2700499) a few minutes before someone else and recieved a couple of upvotes, placing my answer on top of the list; however, he provides a more thorough answer than I do.

Then, after some discussion in comments, someone posted an answer that fixed an oversight in my suggestion. In his post, he explicitly references my answer.

I am relatively new to Stack Overflow, and want to know what is the proper etiquette in this situation.

**Question**

Do I have a responsibility to ensure that their answers move to the top of the list and, if so, which strategy would I use?

- Deleting my post
- Upvoting the other posts
- Requesting that one of the other answers be marked correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either remove your answer if you like, but you don't have to. Why not improve your own answer to make it better and correct?

You can also upvote the other answers. There is even a badge encouraging such actions - [Sportsmanship](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/805/sportsmanship).

But don't request that any answer should be accepted! That is totally up the the OP.

Comment: Improving my answer would require copying points made by both other posters almost verbatim, which feels wrong. Perhaps this is better for  the community though?

Comment: If you think your answer is useless now, I suggest removing it. If not you can refer to the other answers for things you have missed.

Comment: Added an edit referring to the other post: I figured since it referenced mine by name and expanded upon it, removing my post would be confusing.